# Yo command is not recognized

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am new to these command and following a book to start Angular.js

```
npm install –g grunt-cli
npm install –g bower
npm install –g generator-angular
```

all commands are successfully run then I am creating a folder in C:\StockDog and running the command "yo angular StockDog" but it throws the error that yo command is not recognized. I added the path to PATH variable in MyComputer Environmental variable %AppData%\npm but same error yo command is not found.Please suggest why i am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Yeoman (`npm install -g yo`) to run Yeoman generators such as `generator-angular` - they won't work on their own.

Comment: Also as an aside: I'd *really* recommend learning React, Vue or Angular 2+ instead of Angular.js. The latter is outdated, and quite frankly a massive pain to work with.

Comment: Thanks Joe, but i am getting this Error by running  npm install -g yo command "npm ERR! self signed certificate in certificate chain"

Comment: @Raman: That sounds like an unrelated issue - are you behind a corporate proxy?

Comment: Yes I am connected at my office

Comment: Joe you are simply great..you solved my problem. At home it worked Yo command. Thanks for your help

Comment: @Raman: Glad to hear it :) Office networks often cause issues with NPM due to proxies and self-signed certificates - I'd recommend talking to someone from your company's IT/network department if that's getting in the way of your work.